Breakpoints and Bookmarks no longer appear in gutter in Visual Studio 2022
I am using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.11.2. After adjusting some setting last night, I cannot trigger breakpoints from the gutter.
When I press F9, the line of code gets highlighted red, but no icon is in the gutter.  I would like the original behavior back. I am also unable to see my bookmarks in the gutter now too.



It's a setting. When I import my settings from 3 days ago I do see the Gutter again.  I no longer see the Bookmarks Highlighted Blue.  That is a nice feature.  Would be Curious what the setting for the Gutter is and how to make the Bookmarks Blue.  Thank you

phuzi, I didn't realize vssettings is a text file that I can do a text compare on.  I am new to C#, Visual Studio and Web Development.  Thanks

Most configuration files for VS (and VS Code) are plain text files.

This is called the "Indicator Margin", but many refer to it as the gutter.
You toggle this on/off via Tools → Options → Text Editor → General → Indicator Margin:

With it enabled, your breakpoints and bookmark indicators should be visible once again. Unfortunately, the blue highlight for lines that are bookmarked appears to only work when you have the indicator margin disabled.
